# How to properly import pspice models

Tags: circuit-design, simulation, pspice

Some .lib models have several subcircuits, however when you export a part (.olb) you can only select one subcircuit and export. As shown in the image below, there is MAX2408, SHDN, MAX4265a, etc.

As each subcircuit is dependent on the other, the complete circuit is not converted to a symbol.

What is the best way to encapsulate all subcircuits in the .lib file and then export to a .olb?

[image]